# Google Maps for AngularJS Model Example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have access to an api please see (http://www.myperkpoint.com/api/v1/perks?lat=53.541962&long=-2.126436&access_token=8f8d9a9d7cdc08cebc387b42af6e5492) I am tiring to use it with http://angular-google-maps.org/api#markers but i am not having any luck my code so far

```
.controller('MapController', function($scope, perksFactory) {

    $scope.perks = perksFactory.getPerks();

    $scope.map = {
        center: {
            latitude: 53.544546,
            longitude: -2.118732
        },
        zoom: 8
    };

})
```

My View

```
<google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true">
    <markers models='{{ perks }}' coords="{{ perks.company.coords }}"></markers>
</google-map>
```

Answer (score 2):

According with the provided url, I'd say

```
<google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true">
    <markers models="perks" coords="'company.coords'"></markers>
</google-map>
```

Comment: when i run it i get ERROR: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/ng/areq?p0=InfoController&p1=not<span class="angular-google-maps-windows" ng-transclude="" show="'showWindow'" closeclick="'closeClick'">0a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
2014-06-25 10:58:49.665 MyPerkPoint[1712:60b] ERROR: Error: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'b.coords.latitude')

Comment: it's complicated to give you a hand with a few information. If you have a fiddle or something like that would be better